# Label generate slightly below span or input in Jade/Pug

Tags: html, css, pug

I trying to create a form in Jade (Pug), but when my spans and radio buttons are generate slightly above my labels for each entry. It looks like this: [image]

I would like all of the text to align with the labels. This is all within a form. My Jade code is as follows:

```
form.inline-form(ng-submit="submit()")

    .option-group(ng-show="visible('checkCountry')")
        #checkboxes
            label Does this country have a code?
            span &nbsp;Yes&nbsp;
            input(type='radio', name='checkCountry', value='true', id = 'yes', ng-click="showCountries = false; displayIdentifierInput = true", checked="checked")
            span &nbsp;No&nbsp;
            input(type='radio', name='checkCountry', value='false', id = 'no',ng-click="showCountries = true; displayIdentifierInput = false")

    .option-group(ng-show="showCountries && visible('checkCountry')")
        #selectcountry
            label Country
            select#countryName(required, ng-model="selectedCountry", ng-options="options", ng-change="function()")


    .option-group(ng-show="!displayIdentifierInput && visible('checkCountry')")
        #autogeneratedtext
            label Identifier
            span A temporary identifier will be generated automatically
```

The CSS that applies is this:

```
inline-form .option-group label {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    width: 192px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
}
.option-group label span {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.inline-form .option-group label+input, .inline-form .option-group label+textarea, .inline-form .upload {
    width: 340px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Also, how could I avoid using `&nbps' to create my space between radio inputs? Thanks!